# TypeError: window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand is not a function

Tags: javascript, errors, tinymce

I can't add any shortcode in my wordpress editor. it shows -

TypeError: window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand is not a function

window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(id, 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode)
. please help me to solve this.
Full code :-

```
function submitData($form) {
    try {
        $form = $form || jQuery('form');
        if(window.tinyMCE) {
            var selectedContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent(),
                id = tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId || 'content',
                shortcodeName = $form.attr('name'),
                shortcode = ' [' + shortcodeName + ' ';

            $form.find('[data-name]').each(function() {
                var $this   =   jQuery(this),
                    type    =   $this.data('type'),
                    value   =   ($this.attr('type') == 'checkbox')
                            ?   ($this.is(':checked')) ? 'on' : ''
                            :   $this.val() || '';
                value = fitValue(type, value);
                shortcode += $this.data('name') + '="' + value + '" ';
            });
            shortcode += ']' + selectedContent + '[/' + shortcodeName + '] ';

            window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(id, 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode)
            tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceRepaint');
            tinyMCEPopup.close();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813970/typeerror-window-tinymce-execinstancecommand-is-not-a-function

Thanks to [Scott B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209102/scott-b)

In Wordpress 3.9, the TinyMCE is updated to version 4, and in TinyMCE 4, the method "execInstanceCommand" has been replaced by the method "execCommand".

For compatibility issue (with old versions of WP), you must be check the TinyMCE version and used the suitable method.

In below, i changed your code. The commented lines of code are mine.

```
function submitData($form) {
    try {
        $form = $form || jQuery('form');
        if(window.tinyMCE) {

            /* get the TinyMCE version to account for API diffs */
            var tmce_ver=window.tinyMCE.majorVersion;

            var selectedContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent(),
                id = tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId || 'content',
                shortcodeName = $form.attr('name'),
                shortcode = ' [' + shortcodeName + ' ';

            $form.find('[data-name]').each(function() {
                var $this   =   jQuery(this),
                    type    =   $this.data('type'),
                    value   =   ($this.attr('type') == 'checkbox')
                            ?   ($this.is(':checked')) ? 'on' : ''
                            :   $this.val() || '';
                value = fitValue(type, value);
                shortcode += $this.data('name') + '="' + value + '" ';
            });
            shortcode += ']' + selectedContent + '[/' + shortcodeName + '] ';

            /* Check for TinyMCE version */
            if (tmce_ver >= 4) {
                /* In TinyMCE 4, we must be use the execCommand */
                window.tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, shortcode);
            } else {
                /* In TinyMCE 3x and lower, we must be use the execInstanceCommand */
                 window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(id, 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode);
            }
            tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceRepaint');
            tinyMCEPopup.close();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Nice but can you ellaborate on why this works without requiring the user to click on the link? Distil it down to the relevant part and quote it

Comment: Please replace the code: "window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(id, 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode)" with my code.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include that? It's not apparent just having code written with no explanation or context

Comment: The code is updated...

Comment: You haven't explained what you changed or how it fixes the issue, a copy paste of code doesn't help anyone understand what the issue was and how it was fixed

Comment: The error stil !!